# Накопительная сумма в SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Нужно посчитать накопительную сумму в таблице с измененным порядком строк (отсортированной по нескольким полям). Получается, нельзя использовать запрос вида:

```
Select sum(p.val) as sm 
from test p, test v
where p.id<=v.id
```

,так как задать условие "where p.id<=v.id" я не могу. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте явный `join`

```
Select v.id, sum(p.val) as sm 
from test p
inner join test v
  on p.id<=v.id
group by v.id
```